# NetMiko KeyError in Connection Dictionary

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, netmiko

I'm trying to make my automation script I have written in python and NetMiko more Object-Oriented.
I'm trying to extend the base ConnectionHandler class and create my own callable function from the new class that can be threaded.
To start I'm just trying to call the connection object from main.
the code exits with return code 1, KeyError: 'device_type'. I've tried adding other classes to extend from, such as ssh_dispatcher, and BaseConnection, but that doesn't work.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

HostAddressVW = "127.0.0.1"
UserNameVW = "*********"
PassWordVW = "*********"
PortNumVW = 51002
SecretPassVW = "*********"

voice_ware = {'device_type': 'linux',
              'session_log': 'session.txt',
              'host': HostAddressVW,
              'username': UserNameVW,
              'password': PassWordVW,
              'port': PortNumVW,
              'verbose': True,
              'secret': PassWordVW
              }


class NetConnect(ConnectHandler()):

    def net_connection(self):
        
        voice_ware = {'device_type': 'linux',
                      'session_log': 'session.txt',
                      'host': HostAddressVW,
                      'username': UserNameVW,
                      'password': PassWordVW,
                      'port': PortNumVW,
                      'verbose': True,
                      'secret': PassWordVW
                      }
        connection_object = ConnectHandler(**voice_ware)

        connection_object.enable()

        output = connection_object.send_command("uname -r")

        print(output)


def main():

    NetConnect.net_connection()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\b*******\PycharmProjects\pbxextchange01\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    class NetConnect(ConnectHandler()):
  File "C:\Users\b*******\PycharmProjects\pbxextchange01\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 354, in ConnectHandler
    device_type = kwargs["device_type"]
KeyError: 'device_type'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Why is your class inheriting from ConnectHandler? I don't see the use case, but you are creating the object with `NetConnect(ConnectHandler())` and would need to do  `NetConnect(ConnectHandler)`. But I think you don't need polymorphism.

Comment: I tried that, however, when I use NetConnect(ConnectHandler) it gives me an error: class NetConnect(ConnectHandler):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str. I don't have a definite use case beyond trying to create an inherited class and call it instead of directly calling from netmiko module

Comment: So ConnectHandler is a function and not a class. You can not create an inherited class from a function. It does not make sense.